# How do I get and log all Linq To Db queries to a database table?

Tags: linq, linq2db

I need to get the execution plan of all Linq To Db queries for my application, and them to a database table for any query that takes longer than 2 minutes. How do I get an execution plan, and is there one place where I can do this for all queries in the app?

Comment: For sure there is no way. Execution plan is created by Database Engine, SQL Server for example. You have to setup some monitoring tool like [Solarwinds DPA](https://www.solarwinds.com/database-performance-analyzer) (free for 14 days) and analyse performance gaps.

Comment: Check this out https://linq2db.github.io/

Comment: If it is difficult to identity which LINQ query is slow, use `query.TagQuery("My super dashboard query")` and `linq2db` will add comment to the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Tracing to `DataOptions`

```cs
var options = new DataOptions();
options = options
   .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
   .UseTracing(TraceLevel.Info, ti => 
   {
        if (ti.TraceInfoStep == TraceInfoStep.AfterExecute && ti.ExecutionTime != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ti.SqlText);
            // here you can filter out long running queries
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + ti.ExecutionTime.TotalSeconds);
        }
   });

using var dc = new DataConnection(options);
```

Collecting execution plan is not possible. It is done on the Database engine side.